# Create expanded lookup Visualforce page

Tags: salesforce1-app

I am trying to add a Visualforce element into my Salesforce1 app.

I have created a simple Visualforce page, however it does not appear in "Expanded lookups" list.

Here's very simple code I use:

```
<apex:page >
    <img src="{!$Resource.order2}"/>
</apex:page>
```

And here's what I see:

[image]

Been Googling like crazy for ages and couldn't find anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanded Lookups are for expanding standard and custom relationships. Visualforce pages will appear as available for a layout when the "standardController" property matches the object's name:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <!-- my content here -->
</apex:page>
```